# Too much recursion in console log - on click

Tags: jquery, click

I keep getting too much recursion in console log and crashing my firefox browser. I understand it is to do with my `$(this).find('i.pl-action').click();`
How can i solve this?

Code:

```
$( document ).on("click", "#genre-playlist-entries li.playlistclicked", function()
{
    $("li.active", "#playlist").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).find('i.pl-action').click();
    $(".playlistcontentLoad").attr("data-path", $(this).attr("data-path"));
});
```

Comment: lets see... so, on click, lets trigger a click, that triggers a click, taht triggers a click, solve it by... not triggering a click on click? If it's a jquery click handler, you could just trigger the handler.

Comment: You are triggering an event that clicks within the document, on the click event of the document....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the click handler for `i.pl-action` write `e.stopPropogation()` that will prevent the child click from propogating to the parent and hece prevent recursion

```
$(function(){

   $('i.pl-action').on('click', function(e) {
       e.stopPropogation();
    })
    $( "#genre-playlist-entries li.playlistclicked" ).on("click", function()
    {
        $("li.active", "#playlist").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).find('i.pl-action').click();
        $(".playlistcontentLoad").attr("data-path", $(this).attr("data-path"));
    });

})
```

Comment: Could you check one thing, is the first click event getting called by addingconsole.log('in i click')  and are you using trigger instead of click();

Comment: you are using trigger right and also the `$('i.pl-action').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropogation();
})` is written above your `$( document ).on("click", "#genre-playlist-entries li.playlistclicked", function(`

Comment: Correct, i added the above code directly into my source. So it is in the same order. But sadly i dont get output in the `$('i.pl-action').click`

Comment: Same issue. too much recursion! :/

Comment: It gets into the `$( document ).on("click"` but not the `$('i.pl-action').on`.

Comment: We will get that yet haha! Wont go into either now.

Comment: How did you get around with the error you were facing. What was the mistake we failed to spot that time

Comment: I didnt get it fixed, i re designed and didnt use the on click event but instead i used click on the element.